# Lazy loading with wpf Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, lazy-loading

Initially I am populating 100 rows in Data grid, when user scroll the grid rows, I want to populate another 100 rows. I am using wpf data grid, I have not found any event of data grid that I can catch to accomplish this task. Then I have used scroll viewer control and try to catch change event where I know that my **scroll viewer reach at end**, then I will load another rows in data grid.

```
 <ScrollViewer Name="svDataGrid" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" >
            <DataGrid VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"   Background="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="dgList" Grid.Row="1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Azure"
                 CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                 CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                 CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="dgList_MouseDoubleClick"  PreviewKeyDown="dgList_PreviewKeyDown">
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

any suggestion or hint appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be looking at data virtulization.

Please refer http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: That is an old answer, but still simple google search gave another http://www.devzest.com/blog/post/wpf-data-virtualization.aspx and http://www.codemag.com/article/1407081

Comment: Thanks. My point was that a link is not an answer, case in point. Should have been more clear in my comment.