# WPF Datagrid: Lazy Loading / Inifinite scroll

Tags: wpf, database, datagrid, scroll, virtualization

I fill the Datagrid with 250 rows. When the user scrolls down using the scrollbar (below 75% for example), I want to fetch the next 250 rows from the database, and so on. The idea is that the grid could have millions of results and we don't want to load them all, until the user requests them. Is there an existing mechanism for this?

EDIT: Because there seem to be a lot of confusion: I'm not looking for the standard data virtualization solutions, I already use [them](http://www.devzest.com/blog/post/WPF-Data-Virtualization.aspx). But they all require you to specify the number of 'virtual rows' in advance, and that query is to costly for me. The reason why they require it is because it's makes it so much easier to calculate the current page/offset/etc when you know the total items in the grid. But it is a very costly sql-query to calculate that amount, so I want to migrate to another solution where I can skip the COUNT() query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy loading with wpf Data Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939543/lazy-loading-with-wpf-data-grid)

Comment: You're right. But that question has accepted 'use datavirtualization' as an answer. I already use that, so for me that's no answer to the question, just an alternative.

Comment: Now I got the point. Virtualization can help when a DataContext/ItemsSource already bound to an entire data set, but you need a lazy loading on the data access level

Comment: Are you using WPF 3.5 or WPF 4?

Comment: @Joshua Are you asking for UI Virtualization or Data Virtualization? If UI, the answer below is correct. If Data, the link sll posted is correct.

Comment: Joshua, mentionning Virtualization in the Q would have saved a Close vote and could prevent wasted effort in that direction.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do realize that `Data virtualization != UI Virtualization`? i.e. the blog post in the answer on the other question could actually be what you are looking for...

Comment: @H.B. I already use code exactly like shown on that blog. My grid has a million virtual rows, and their content only gets filled (through SQL) when they scroll into the view. But ALL those solutions require you to know the total number of rows in advance, Im looking for something that lets number of rows dynamicly increase, not virtualize them.

Answer (score 5):

So looks like Virtualization property of DataGrid wouldn't help you because it requires a full data set to be in the `ItemsSource`.

So to have in place a data lazy loading (See an article [Data Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344)) You can handle [ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx) event and apply a classical server-side paging approach. Basically you have to define and calculate such sings like `Page Size`, `Page Number`, `Sort Order` in this way you can request from a data base a required data set and show it on UI. Each time when `Current  Page Number` or `Sort Order` is changing you need to request a data and update `ItemsSource` of the grid, also perhaps you need to restore Scroll Position as well but I'm not sure in this.

- Calculate number of visible items
- Do a data request to database usign parametrized query with parameters like PageNumber, PagiSize
- Update DataGrid ItemsSource by a just loaded data items

I believe a main challenge would be to calculate a value of Page Size, Current Page Number. I believe [Logical Scrolling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx#scrollviewer_physical_vs_logical) mode would help you in this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid you're right that I would have to write my own logic for this. I really hoped there was an existing component or example code that I could use as a base.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this Muis?

Answer (score -1):

Set DataGrid's `EnableRowVirtualization` property to `true`

Rows will therefore be loaded when user scrolls, so only the visible rows will actually be loaded

Comment: I currently use data virtulization for the grid, but it forces me to know how many rows there will be in total, and for some queries I dont want to calculate that.

Comment: You do not appear to have understood the question, virtualization only creates the visual representation of data when needed, the question was how to fetch said data only when needed, that is on a completely different layer.

Comment: Now I understand the question, as your edit made it clearer :) sorry for misleading you :/