# Progress bar during load of virtualised wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, virtualization

I am using the normal WPF DataGrid to display some data from a REST feed.  The REST feed is paged with a next link that contains the URL for the next set of items.  The DataGrid is virtualised by having a custom object that implements the IList interface (not IList), and knows how to fetch missing data from the REST feed.

The issue is that if a user scrolls immediately to the bottom this component must do a bunch of REST requests for each "next" page, causing the GUI to freeze.  Of course I could simply put up a "wait" screen, but I would actually be able to show an accurate progress bar.

So to accomplish this I have a progress bar on my application status bar that has visibility set to IsLoading on the data context, which in turn passes this down to the paging object.  There is another property LoadedPercentage which shows how much of the required data has been loaded.

The issue is that when I scroll to the end of the screen, it still freezes and shows nothing.  I set breakpoints in the code to see if my properties were being accessed and they were all hit at the correct times and showed the correct values.  So I deduce from this that the DataGrid itself is somehow stopping the GUI thread from doing any drawing while it waits for the IList object to return the requested object.

**So does anyone know of a solution for getting the status bar to show up?**  I would really rather have the status bar appear and track progress rather than some "loading please wait" screen.  **Can this be done at all with the built in objects or do we have to purchase some third party grid?**

EDIT:  It wasn't completely clear to some so I wanted to mention: I am doing virtualisation as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) among other places.  It seems that when the DataGrid requests a specific entry it blocks the entire UI painting until it the request completes.

Comment: Z not S.  virtualized

Comment: Z is the american spelling, S is the british spelling.  My spell checker is set to British apparently and I'm not willing to fight with it over this. :)

Comment: Only a comment but I don't think a 3rd party control will help.  Once the UI starts to paint all it does is paint.

Answer (score 0):

Well, UI is busy fetching data from the REST service. If you don't like the behaviour, you can implement data virtualization.

This post explains more: [WPF Datagrid: Lazy Loading / Inifinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581732/wpf-datagrid-lazy-loading-inifinite-scroll)

As far I know, there is no "ready" solution in WPF, and it will be little hassle, but it should work with some tweaking.

Implementing your custom IList doesn't sound like it would work, so I am not sure about how to "fix" your solution, and if it's even possible.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously wasn't clear enough.  I will edit my answer.  I am already doing WPF DataGrid virtualisation as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) and other places.

Comment: Just to confirm this: what do you think the issue is? I mean, it seems like UI is blocking, so it can't display anything other for that time, however, why do you think it is blocking? Are you using asynchronous lazy loading? Don't deal with more than 20 items at once. Use ObservableCollection and add items in patch of 20, every 5ms or so. This way ProgressBar has time to run. Also, profile your code to see where the time goes.

Comment: The issue is: if you bind Items on a DataGrid to an object that implements IList, it will use the indexer ([]) to get the specific items it needs.  So what I do is detect when a value was asked for that isn't present, I go fetch it.  If this takes a long time to do it seems to block any painting operations.  I have verified, with breakpoints and checking the stack trace, that the main window is indeed seeing the values set to make the status bar show up.  It seems that the whole UI thread isn't painting until IList.[] returns so it simply isn't seen.  And I try not to load any data unseen data